# как реализовать такую карусель переделав бутстрап? это вообще разумно?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, bootstrap

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Проблема в том, что странно листает бутстрап карусель, я так понимаю js бутстрапа нужно менять?

Comment: https://codepen.io/nagorniy/pen/zwBdpj

Comment: Не понял вопроса - надо сделать карусель как на рисунке? Чтобы были видны огрызки картинок слева и справа?

Comment: да, именно, и при этом когда третий слайд по центру, справа появлялся первый

Comment: Используйте slick slider http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/ , например в Center Mode

Comment: А зачем использовать карусель boostrap если можно взять, ту что подойдет? Мазохизм? Можно переделать конечно, что угодно. Вопрос зачем? Не думаю что найдутся люди, которые подобным будут заниматься.